# Select table two times - not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Actually I have the following database schema:

```
* events
id type player match

* players
id name

* matches
id date
```

The event type can be "A" for assistances or "G" for goals. I need to select the two types in the same query to calculate an offensive production (assistances + goals * 2).

The final result need to be:

year player assistances goals off_production

I have tried the following query, but it's not working (it's returning wrong data):

```
SELECT COUNT(assist.id) AS assistances, COUNT(goals.id) AS goals, (assistances + goals * 2) AS off_prod, p.name AS player, YEAR(m.date) AS year 
FROM matches AS m, players AS p, events AS assist, events AS goals  
WHERE assist.match = m.id AND
assist.type ="A" AND
assist.player = p.id AND 
goals.match = j.id AND 
goals.type ="G" AND
goals.player = p.id
GROUP BY year, player
ORDER BY year DESC, off_prod DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't you learned to use proper join syntax?  Can you update your question to have explicit joins with the conditions in the `on` clause?

Comment: What is the right data?

Comment: `assistances + goals * 2` This seems confusing? Do you mean `A+G*2`

Comment: I think you need to have one more table , for the match type and the cost

Comment: My query it's returning values different from expected (I have checked mannually). The offensive production is the count of "A" event types + count of "G" event types x 2.

Comment: @EneasGesing I don't believe you get any result at all, because you have at least three errors in your query. You cannot use `assistances` or `goals` in the columns list. Furthermore, `j.id` doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: The query, as written, shouldn't return the wrong data.  It should generate an error that the table alias `j` is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
SELECT assistances
      ,goals
      ,(A.assistances + A.goals * 2) AS off_prod
      ,player
      ,`YEAR`
FROM (
SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN e.`type` ='A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS assistances
      ,COUNT( CASE WHEN e.`type` ='G' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS goals
      ,p.`Name`       AS player
      ,YEAR(m.`date`) AS `year`
FROM       `players`  AS p 
INNER JOIN `events`   AS e     ON p.`id` = e.`player`
INNER JOIN `matches`  AS m     ON e.`match` = m.`id`
GROUP BY p.`name`, YEAR(m.`date`)

) A
ORDER BY A.`year` DESC, (A.assistances + A.goals * 2)  DESC
```

### [`Working Sql Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7893/11)

Comment: Yet the only difference will be to replace the square brackets `[]` with back-ticks around column names, The rest should work fine.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sir I believe so that is the only different please correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @OlafDietsche have a look now [`Working Sql Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7893/11)